# Ending sentences with prepositons

Tags: prepositions, american-english

I'm currently writing up some professional documentation and I know ending sentences with a preposition is frowned upon. Are there any English rules for converting these types of sentences that are more Grammarly correct?

An example is:
"Session dates to search within."

Comment: 1) That doesn't seem to be a full sentence, more like a label for a field. Maybe as a sentence it would be "These are the session dates to search between" ? 2) one way to fix is to reword entirely: "Date search range:".

Comment: It definitely  is an incomplete sentence and that's the first mistake I need to correct.